# Assume that $∂_1g_2 = ∂_2g_1$. Show that $∂_1f(x, y) = g_1(x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let g:$\mathbb{R}^2$ → $\mathbb{R}^2$, $g(x) = (g_1(x), g_2(x))$ be continuously differentiable. Let
$$f(x,y)=\int_0^x {g_1(x,0)dt}  + \int_0^y {g_2(x,s)ds}$$
I have shown $∂_2f(x, y) = g_2(x, y)$.

Assuming that $∂_1g_2 = ∂_2g_1$, I want to show that $∂_1f(x, y) = g_1(x, y)$.

I started by calculating the partial derivative of f with respect to x, $∂_1f(x, y)$.
$$∂_1f(x, y)=g_1(x,0)+\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^y {g_2(x,s)ds}$$
$$=g_1(x,0)+\int_0^y {∂_1g_2(x,s)ds}$$
using Leibnitz' rule. Then,
$$g_1(x,0)+\int_0^y {∂_1g_2(x,s)ds}=g_1(x,0)+\int_0^y {∂_2g_1(x,s)ds}$$
$$=g_1(x,0)+g_1(x,y)$$
I'm not sure if what I have done so far is correct and I'm not sure how to get to $∂_1f(x, y)=g_1(x,y)$.